# Always dropped down menu in android

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, menu

I have an css menu, originally a template, now customized (but only graphical design). On PC it works well but I have problems at e.g. Android phone (Chrome browser). Only the MENU sign should be visible but from the beginning all menu items are dropped down. In addition, when you put it hidden, it pop-up again when you scroll down the page. It is very annoying.

URL e.g. http://k154.fsv.cvut.cz

This should be relavant piece of code:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will need to see your code. Use plunkr or upload your files to github and supply a link.

Note - If you are animating your menu with css try adding 'animation-fill-mode: forwards' to keep the state of the open / closed menu.